# Spell check SAP

Tags: class, methods, ms-word, abap, spell-checking

I followed this tutorial, [Tutorial Spell Check](https://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/f449b290-0201-0010-0d8e-bb9e91317bd3), to implement a spell checker in an ABAP-based system.

This solution is working well, however there is a small issue, when I execute the function module, the spell check appears behind the SAP GUI window. To be able to see the spell check, I need to minimize the window and then maximize it.

I tried to implement the method `set_visible`, `set_enable` but they do not work. Does someone know what the issue might be?

Comment: I forgot to refer, that I tried this function module 'LXE_SP_CHECKSPELLING_MS' and the behavior is the same.

Comment: I have just checked it and the window appears in front of the SAP window. I use Windows 7 professional and SAP GUI 730 patch 5. Could you share your environment details, especially operating system and the version of SAP GUI?

Comment: I use the SAP GUI 730 patch 0, but the client uses SAP GUI 720 and he have the same problem.

Comment: If possible try to upgrade to the newest patch. It is hard to say anything more if you are not on the latest version of it.